# Unable to add ListFolder to Mobile App - even according to documented example

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to add a ListFolder to the Main menu of the Mobile app.  All I am doing is trying to follow the directions in the attached 2019-R1-Mobile-Framework-Dev-Guide as published by Acumatica.

It does not work.  What is very odd, is that I can add all of the HubFolder’s I want.  That works perfectly.  But I can NOT add a ListFolder.

Does anyone know why that would happen?

There are no errors.  It just does not work.

Answer (score 0):

This is NOT well documented.  How you need to do this is a two-step process.

1. you create the "update sitemap" and add those "item" entries there
2. then you *must* create separate "add screen" options

This was not clear at all in the documentation anywhere.